# trying to loop through an array. having problem in displaying them

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

```
if(Event.data.length){
  for(let i=0;i<Event.data.length){
    dat=i;
    console.log(dat);
  }
}else{
  <Loader />
}
```

getting the data from a server where I have data which I wanna loop through but I'm not able to loop. getting only the last value of the loop. But when console.logging that variable. I'm getting two output

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to display that number on the page but it's showing ('1') at the top left.
but when console.logging I'm getting the ('0','1').

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the increment option in the for loop like:

```
 mongos>var x=["a","b","c"];if(x.length){for(i=0;i<x.length;i++) {print(x[i])}}else{print("do nothing")}
a
b
c
mongos>
```